# Styling NavigationDrawer Header

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I was wondering if it is possible to style the NavigationDrawer Header with css some way.

I wish i can actually post all the various things I have tried.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm out of my wits here

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/). Its a handy tool to look into the scene-graph and understand various controls along with their components.

NavigationDrawer is divided into 3 parts:

- Header
- Item(s)
- Footer

Header has a style-class `header` assigned to it. Therefore, you can always access it using:

```
.navigation-drawer.header {
    // your custom css
}
```

Header consists of a VBox, style-class `header-content`.

```
.navigation-drawer.header > .header-content {
    // your custom css
}
```

It consists of 2 HBox. One to store the header image and the other to store the text. The title and sub-title labels can be styled using the following css:

```
.navigation-drawer.header > .header-content > .text-box > * > .title {
   // your custom css
}

.navigation-drawer.header > .header-content > .text-box > * > .subtitle {
   // your custom css
}
```